# How can I display a pop-up when I click on a button with this code :?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

1. Heading

   ### I'm trying to do this [Text and Pop-Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwvk6.png) but with a button.

Here is my code

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
  <li class="center-block">
    <a class="button red text-center" href="tel:514-677-3413">
      <i class="fas fa-phone">APPELEZ-NOUS</i>
    </a>
  </li>
```

I need to place that code to make the text of the popu-up appear but I don't know where in the div

```
<span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
```

Comment: APPELEZ-NOUS is your code?

Comment: my code is ;<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
             <li class="center-block">  <a class="button red text-center" href="tel:514-677-3413"><i class="fas fa-phone">APPELEZ-NOUS</i class="fas fa-phone"></a>

Comment: @inmedia998 Please don't comment code! please edit your original question with the code :)

Comment: Please post it in the question, and your attempt with all the relevant code.

Comment: Do you have javascript or jquery? If you do, please show us that... Also please show that you have done research. If you haven't, you should do that first. Always remember that Stackover Flow should be the last resource if you literally cannot find anything else. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

@inmedia998

Please try this code it works as per your requirement.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/1.5.10/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Click the button and Open simple Pop-Up Box</h3>
<div id="PopupDemo" style="margin:50px; width:55px;" data-clipboard-text="1">Click Me</div>

<script>
        $('#PopupDemo').tooltip({
          trigger: 'click',
          placement: 'top'
        });
        
        function setTooltip(message) {
          $('#PopupDemo').tooltip('hide')
            .attr('data-original-title', message)
            .tooltip('show');
        }
        
        function hideTooltip() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $('#PopupDemo').tooltip('hide');
          }, 1000);
        }
  
        var clipboard = new Clipboard('#PopupDemo');
        
        clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
          setTooltip('A Simple Popup!');
          hideTooltip();
        });
        
        clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
          setTooltip('Failed!');
          hideTooltip();
        });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.